# Mapear response de retrofit, en ocaciones solo una propiedad, en otras ocaciones todo un objeto

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, model

Qué tal, tengo la siguiente respuesta de una ruta, mi interceptor si me lee toda la respuesta, pero al momento de mapearla, tengo el siguiente problema.

```
{
   "error":false,
   "object":[
      {
         "_id":"5e2892df1c02ba00216e5687",
         "name":"Administrador de Organización - 5bb7e51d25dc890011f04165",
         "description":"Administrador de Organización.",
         "organization":{
            "_id":"5cffeb4e1d903538be25f582",
            "createdAt":"2019-06-11T17:56:31.385Z",
            "updatedAt":"2020-07-20T22:58:45.009Z",
            "image":"5de55b1b6ca5ee00108306ce",
            "name":"CompanyName"
      }}
   ]
}
```

Mi propiedad organization, en veces me viene solo con el _id, y en veces si trae sus demás propiedades, de momento lo tengo (porque ya estaba así, este fue un cambio que acaban de agregar) solo con organization con una propiedad _id:String?, y funciona bien cuando solo trae el _id en forma de string, pero cuando trae todo lo demas (Osea en forma de objeto), no se como mapearlo, me creé un data class con las demás propiedades mapeadas, pero ahí me falla cuando solo trae el _id en forma de string.

Muestro el otro json con la propiedad como string.

```
{
   "error":false,
   "object":[
      {
         "_id":"5e2892df1c02ba00216e5687",
         "name":"Administrador de Organización - 5bb7e51d25dc890011f04165",
         "description":"Administrador de Organización.",
         "organization":"5cffeb4e1d903538be25f582"
      }
   ]
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si estás haciendo el servidor vos mismo no te recomiendo hacer esto, por que tener dos tipos de respuestas distintas para una misma consulta va a generar mas logica en tu cliente , además imaginate que eso es un array de objetos, y uno puede tener el objeto organization completo y otros no, se va a hacer mucho lio para convertirlo y no te va a servir usar un converter como gson, seguramente tengas que hacer tu propio converter a mano y agregarlo a retrofit

Comment: Cierto, lo malo es que no soy yo quien hace el servidor. Por eso me toca complicarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como pusieron en los comentarios es una mala práctica realizar eso, pero si no hay forma de cambiarlo lo que podrías hacer es que la llamada que haces devuelva un objeto JSON y luego mediante un try catch valides el tipo ( si tuvieras una forma de saber cuando devuelve solo un string o el objeto organization podrías manejar un flag).

Un ejemplo totalmente genérico seria así:

```
RetrofitClient.get().getDataFromServer(params, new Callback<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void success(JSONObject json, Response response) {
        //En caso sepas cuando viene cual tipo, puedes utilizar un flag
        //if(flag) {
            //Usar GSON para serializar la clase Organization       
        //} else {
            // devolver el String como tal
        //}

        //Caso contrario puede intentar castearlo con un try catch
        
        try{
           //Parsear el objeto JSONOBJECT de la primera forma
        }catch(Exception e){
           //Como no se puede parsear de la primera forma, lanzará un error
           // entonces deberias parearlo de la otra forma
        }
    }
});
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Ciertamente es mala práctica, pero no tuve opción. Al final esto fue lo que termine haciendo. Gracias por responder. De igual manera, mi recomendación es evitar esto lo mas que se pueda.